# Windows 2008 R2 server with exchange 2010 to Windows server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, exchange, mailbox

I am soon going to be moving from our dedicated server windows 2008 R2, to our in house Windows 2003 server.

I am worried about moving everyone's email over as I've never done this before. I gather there is a mailbox database that i need to backup but I'm sure its not that easy.

I am worried that I may not install exchange 2010 on my windows 2003 server correctly and the database won't reinstall and all our staff with loose email or I can't get it mounted etc..

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated

Thanks

Lee

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! There appears to be little to no research done on this issue up front.  A simple search or understanding of Exchange 2010 would show that this cannot be done.  As pointed out in the comments below as well you concede and then ask about RAM requirements (which is capacity planning and cannot be answered beyond minimum requirements posted by MS).  As such I'm voting to close this question.  You need to research and understand Exchange 2010 or hire a consultant that can assist with migration and implementation.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't really make sense. But if it's not a mistake and you really need to move from a Windows Server 2008 R2 server running Exchange Server 2010 to a Windows Server 2003 one, then... no way.

Sorry.

Can't be done.

You can't install Exchange Server 2010 on Windows Server 2003.

Comment: I know its a weird ask, but server 2003 is all we have in house, we are getting a leased line internet and wanted to get rid of our dedicated server to host in house

Comment: Well, you can't. There are many ways of moving Exchange installations around, but none of them will let you move to a previous version of the product.

Comment: "I am worried that I may not install exchange 2010 on my windows 2003 server correctly". Exchange 2010 requires a "64-bit edition of Windows Server 2008" or later. Period. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996719(EXCHG.141).aspx

Comment: OK so I need to get Server 2008 R2 yes ?? whats the minimum ram i need for this with Exchange 2010 installed please ?

Comment: Start with reading the rest of the link I Googled for you.